# Official abbreviation for the site name

Tags: discussion

Is there any official abbreviation for the site name? The name itself - Project Management Stack Exchange (or Project Management at Stack Exchange) - begs for some short version but I've seen a number of different flavors:

- PMSE
- PM@SE
- Project Mangement SE (cold be PM SE)

Should we choose one and use it to refer to the site? If so which one would you choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would choose PMSE.

It is simple and easy to use.

Comment: I've been using `PMSE`.  It's really easy to type.  We're used to typing `PM` when referring to "project manager" and we're used to seeing `SE` when referring to "Stack Exchange".

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a growing trend on meta-so to suffix "-SE" any stack exchange sites, so I would go for PM-SE.